# IMO problems with physics relation

Tags: soft-question

Does anyone know who are quite keen and have large information on IMO (International mathematical Olympiads) have any knowledge on problems in the IMO which are highly related to physics? Or like have some applications to physics specifically tailored to that problem? This is because I want to look at some problems in physics which are highly mathematically oriented, but the problems in IPho (International physics Olympiad) does not have too much of a rigorously mathematical solution or require a range of mathematical techniques, but more relaying on underlying concepts etc...